# How to set a SLA in Airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I would like to set an SLA in a Sensor Operator. The [documentation](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#baseoperator) is not too clear about the use of it. So I did a test using the `S3KeySensor` operator which is looking for a file that does not exist. I set the SLA to 30 seconds, I was hoping to see the record after 30 seconds in the [UI](http://localhost/admin/slamiss/) - in SLA misses - but it did not happen. What am I doing wrong?

```py
inputsensor = S3KeySensor(
    task_id="check_for_files_in_s3",
    bucket_key="adp/backload/20136585/",
    wildcard_match=True,
    bucket_name="weblogs-raw",
    s3_conn_id="AWS_S3_CENTRAL",
    timeout=120,
    poke_interval=10,
    sla=timedelta(seconds=30),
    dag=dag,
)

inputsensor.set_downstream(next_step)
```

Comment: ebertbm: Did you get it to work with this configuration?

Comment: Instead of using sla,  you have better fortune using execution_timeout setting the on_failure_callback accordely.

Answer (score 9):

```py
"sla": timedelta(hours=2),
```

An example from Airflow Git repository: [airflow/example_dags/tutorial.py#L54](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/343d38af380afad2b202838317a47a7b1687f14f/airflow/example_dags/tutorial.py#L54).

Comment: I find it strange that passing `SLA` in `default_args` works and passing it directly as param to `operator` doesn't work. Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 9):

According to the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/models/baseoperator.html) SLA represents the timedelta after the schedule period is over. So if your schedule interval is `'@daily'` and `sla=timedelta(hours=1)` then Airflow will check for SLA misses at 1:00 AM which is when the schedule period is over plus one hour.

Answer (score 2):

In hours

```py
"sla": timedelta(hours=2)
```

In minutes

```py
"sla": timedelta(minutes=120)
```